# User timer bugs out after first use and returns zero no matter how long I wait

Tags: c++, timer

Im trying to create a game that tests the reaction speed of the user and for the first part of the game I use a timer to randomize when the user should press. After that I want to time how long time it takes for the user to press but no matter how long i wait to press it always returns "you have pressed 1 after 0 seconds" with 1 being the key i pressed. How do make it so it times the user preferable also in ms instead of seconds. 
Im really new to C++ and trying to self learn with the help of books but im really stuck. Any help?

```
#include <iostream
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;


class timer { 
private:
    unsigned long startTime; 
public:
    void start() {
        startTime = clock(); 
}

unsigned long elapsedTime() { 
    unsigned long t = (clock() - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return t;
}

bool isTimeout(unsigned long seconds) {
    return seconds >= elapsedTime();
}




int main() {
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    int keyPressed = (0);
    unsigned long secondsBeforeStart = (rand() % 11);
    timer tBefore;
    timer tAfter;
    bool waitingInput = false;
    bool gameIsFinished = false;

    tBefore.start();
    cout << "timer started . . ." << endl;
    while(true)
    {
        if(tBefore.elapsedTime() >= secondsBeforeStart && !waitingInput && !gameIsFinished) //waiting the game to draw "Tryck nu!"
    {
            waitingInput = true;
            cout << "Tryck nu!" << endl;
            tAfter.start();
    }
        if(waitingInput && !gameIsFinished) // if "Tryck nu" has appeared => waiting the player to press a key
    {
            // cout << "DEBUG : tAfter == " << tAfter.elapsedTime(); << endl;
            cin >> keyPressed;
            if( keyPressed != 0) // if player press the key
            {
            cout << "you have pressed " << keyPressed << " after " << tAfter.elapsedTime() << " seconds" << endl;
            gameIsFinished = true;
        }
    }
        if(gameIsFinished)
    {
            cout << "Well done, you can push a button to restart the game" << endl;
            cin >> keyPressed;
            if( keyPressed != 0) // if player press the key
        {
                cout << "Restarting" << endl;
                waitingInput = false;
                gameIsFinished = false;
                secondsBeforeStart = (rand() % 11);
                tBefore.start();
                cout << "timer started . . ." << endl;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Your code is invalid because you have missing `};`. Would be obvious if you'd used proper indentation.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be with your elapsedTime() function:

```
unsigned long elapsedTime() { 
    unsigned long t = (clock() - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return t;
}
```

in case you are counting less than `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` ticks - which is very probable - the division will return 0 because the operands are integer types.

Try displaying the clock ticks first and worry about converting the time to seconds after that.

Comment: Im trying to display the clock ticks but i think im doing something wrong, could you give me an example of how it should look.

Comment: @JohanEhr unsigned long t = (clock() - startTime) should display the clock ticks. I recommend trying a simpler scenario, without the complex if statements just to see it works. And then add all the logic you want on top. BUT Lightness Races in Orbit did make a valid point. You probably should consider using gettimeofday().

Answer (score 0):

`clock()` tells you the number of CPU ticks used by the process, but your process doesn't take up any CPU time whilst it's blocked on input! So [it's useless for this kind of problem](http://kera.name/articles/2011/03/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-11-sleep-your-way-to-success/).

You should use a different function instead, one which gives you *wall time* (i.e. absolute passage of real-world time), especially if you want milliseconds-resolution. Consider [`gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday).

```
#include <sys/time.h>

class timer
{ 
private:
    double startTime;

    /**
     * This function wraps the call to `gettimeofday()`,
     * so that you may simply use it instead of `clock()`.
     *
     * You will still have to remove your `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`
     * logic and switch from `unsigned long` to `double`,
     * though.
     */
    double getTime()
    {
       timeval tv;
       gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
       return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec/1e9;
    }

public:
    void start()
    {
        startTime = getTime(); 
    }

    double elapsedTime()
    { 
        return getTime() - startTime;
    }

    bool isTimeout(double seconds) {
        return seconds >= elapsedTime();
    }
};
```

#### ([live demo of class in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a65e7eaf72d5765a))

In a real-world application, I would actually use [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, to avoid the effect of local time jumps. That may be too much in this simple learning case, though.

Comment: I havent worked with gettimeofday() yet. Would it be hard to implement or would i simply replace all "clock()" with gettimeofday()?

Comment: @JohanEhr: I've added an example. In general, to find out how to use a function, read its documentation (I provided links) and Google for examples.

Comment: Cant even get your example to work, I get use of undeclared identifier "gettimeofday" im coding on a mac if that makes any difference

Comment: @JohanEhr: You forgot to copy the `#include` statement. [The function exists on OSX too](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html).